# How can I display <h4> only when filtered results are displayed in particular div or <td>

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Below is my code to display data $topic and $response based on the search input. Now I want to display a heading for each div and only display heading if display happens in div. can you please help
you can find my sample code below

```
<div ng-app="sample" ng-controller="sampleController">        
    <div class="black">      
        <input type="text" name="search" ng-model="search"
               placeholder="search" ng-click="didSelectLanguage()"/>          
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
  <table  style="border: 1px solid black ;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><center><b>Question</b></center></td>
            <td ><center><b>Response</b></center></td>
        </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:searchFilter">
<h4>Heading 1</h4>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black ; width:30%;white-space: pre-wrap;">{{user.gsx$topic.$t}}</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black ; width:70%;white-space: pre-wrap;">{{user.gsx$response.$t}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module('sample', []).
 controller('sampleController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {              
    var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/153Obe1TdWlIPyveZoNxEw53rdrghHsiWU9l-WgGwCrE/1/public/values?alt=json";
// var url2 = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/153Obe1TdWlIPyveZoNxEw53rdrghHsiWU9l-WgGwCrE/2/public/values?alt=json";
    $http.get(url)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {     
         $scope.users = data.feed.entry;
         console.log($scope.users);
    })
    .error(function(error, status, headers, config) {
         console.log(status);
         console.log("Error occured");
    }); 
    $scope.search='';
    $scope.searchFilter=function(item){
        if(item.gsx$topic.$t.indexOf($scope.search) != -1 || item.gsx$response.$t.indexOf($scope.search) != -1){
        return true;
            }
      return false;
    }

}]);
</script>
```

Comment: can some one help me with this

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Solution 1:-**

You could actually save a reference to the filtered results in a variable: h in filtered.marvel = (heroes | filter:{comic:'Marvel'}), which you could use like so: filtered.marvel.length.

*"the Heroes Found!"* div gets added only if the length != 0

```
            <div ng-if="heroes.length != 0"><b>Heroes Found!</b></div>
           <div ng-repeat="h in filtered.marvel = (heroes | filter:{comic:'Marvel'})">
            {{ h.name}} - {{h.comic}}
           </div>
```

See [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bJoqLkFcpuX6HvXbsVLC?p=preview)

Comment: I tried the filter is not working then. can you fix it in my code please!

Comment: Please create a plunkr and post it here. i'll see what i can do.

Comment: can you please look into this question. My actual requirement is this and thought of trying it giving sheet names manually into code rather than getting it from JSON URL.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60069498/how-can-i-get-title-and-hyperlinks-data-from-the-json-ulr-from-google-sheet-expo/60103468#60103468

Comment: Sure, i will look at that too. If You are satisfied with this answer , please mark it as correct. It may help others looking for the same. :)